# Finding ACVF and two random variables

Tags: time-series, covariance

let $X_t = 0.5X_{t-1} + Z_t$ where $Z_t$ ~ $ WN(0,\sigma^2)$

I want to find the ACVF of both $X_t$ and $Z_t$, but I am a little bit confused.
Say for $X_t$
$$\gamma(h) = Cov(0.5X_{t-1} + Z_t, 0.5X_{t-1+h} + Z_{t+h})$$ 
$ = 0.5^2Cov(X_{t-1},X_{t-1+h}) + 0.5Cov(X_{t-1},Z_{t+h}) + 0.5Cov(Z_{t},X_{t-1+h}) + Cov(Z_{t},Z_{t+h}) $

then for say $h =-1$ could I still say that the 
$0.5^2 Cov(X_{t-1},Z_{t+h}) = 0.5 \sigma^2$ ? Or is there a difference because of the differing $X $ and $Z$ terms 
How can I find the covariance between $X$ and $Z$ ?